# Glassfish server Domain starts failed

Tags: java, glassfish

I installed Glassfish sever in my system. The domain is created when i am installing glassfish server. But the domain couldn't started after installation. It shows following Error. Kindly anyone suggest solution for this .

---

```
 enWARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish-corba
-omgapi.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleCont
extImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
Bundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

Aug 03, 2017 9:20:14 AM BundleProvisioner install
WARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish-extra
-jre-packages.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleCont
extImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
Bundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

Aug 03, 2017 9:20:14 AM BundleProvisioner install
WARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish-oracl
e-jdbc-driver-packages.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleCont
extImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
Bundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

Aug 03, 2017 9:20:14 AM BundleProvisioner install
WARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/javax.transacti
on.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleCont
extImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
Bundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

Aug 03, 2017 9:20:14 AM BundleProvisioner install
WARNING: Failed to install file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/performance-tun
er-extra-jre-packages.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleCont
extImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
(BundleProvisioner.java:446)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install
Bundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(Extens
ionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findCla
ss(BundleWiringImpl.java:2128)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDele
gation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1432)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringIm
pl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadCla
ss(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(Bund
leWiringImpl.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:417
0)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1972)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStart
LevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator
not found by org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [75]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDele
gation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringIm
pl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadCla
ss(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 14 more
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.glassfis
h.hk2.osgi-adapter [168]: Unable to resolve 168.0: missing requirement [168.0] o
sgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.enterprise.module)(version>=1
.1.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 95.0: missing requirement [95.0] osgi.wirin
g.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.jvnet.hk2.config)(version>=1.1.0)) [caused
 by: Unable to resolve 23.0: missing requirement [23.0] osgi.wiring.package; (os
gi.wiring.package=javax.management)]]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:382
6)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStart
LevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: org.glassfish.embeddable
.GlassFishException: No GlassFishRuntime available
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: No GlassFishRuntime avai
lable
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.getGlassFishRuntime(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:202)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:162)
        ... 9 more
Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(G
lassFishMain.java:203)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support wa
s removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=64m; support was re
moved in 8.0
ter code here
```

---

I didn't installed NetBeans. My system is only for an act as a server for deploying .war file. I tried a lot of solutions from the internet. No solutions for starting domain. Kindly suggest the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened because my version of glassfish worked with a different JDK version than the one recommended.
Solution:

1. Install the version of JDK compatible with your version of glasshfish.
2. Change the jdk of your glassfish in your `osgi.properties` file:
   Open the file
   `${GLASSFISH_HOME}/glassfish/config/osgi.properties`
   and add this line at the end:
   `jre-1.8=${jre-1.7}`

Answer (score -2):

error is occurring because of missing of  `org.osgi.core` library. you need to use `org.osgi.core` dependency, you can find it below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How can I fix this org.osgi.core library?